# Removing Azure AD DS from subscription

Tags: azure, service, directory

I am looking to delete Azure AD Directory services from my subscription (and remove the subscription). But I want to verify that when I do delete Azure ADDS that user accounts will NOT be effected. I'm keeping the azure AD tenant but want to remove azure adds without interfering with other services.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-disable-aadds

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to user accounts that were created in Azure AD then these will not be affected by deleting AAD DS.

If you created any user accounts or groups directly in AAD DS (outside of the users OU) then these will not exist after deletion, as they only ever existed in AAD DS.